# Array formatted string php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using curl to get response from eventbrite api. I have the following code which is responding me a string formatted as json. I want it to be a json response so I can get the desired data.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103/?token=5TYIZLHG7YG6N73RAUHL");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: Investigate the PHP function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Pass [`TRUE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as its second argument to make it return [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which fixed the problem.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103/?token=5TYIZL‌​HG7YG6N73RAUHL');
$result = json_decode($homepage);
var_dump($result->name);
```

Comment: Is this an addition to your question? Does this fix your problem? What am I looking at? Some context would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are decoding JSON and then echoing object which would probably make it go back to String again.

Try `var_dump( json_decode($result) );`

as `json_decode($result)` would produce Object and if you try to echo out object it will call `__toString` method on that object so you would get nowhere

Comment: How do I get specific data from this response, like `$result['name']`?

Comment: Can you post your sample structure. Since it's an object you would probably have `$result->name`, but it could be collection of objects so you would have maybe `$result[0]->name`

Comment: I have found the solution. Their api is underdevelopment.

Comment: `$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/categories/103/?token=5TYIZLHG7YG6N73RAUHL');
$result  = json_decode($homepage);
var_dump($result->name)`